# A intentService won't be killed by System?

Tags: android, process

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html), every android component run in the same **process** by default. So when call startService to start an intentService in **UI thread**. The intentService actually run in the same **process**, but a different thread called **worker thread**, right?

And System could kill any application **process** if there is not enough memory. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) of intentService, it only stops itself once runs out of work. Does it means that the **process** which runs IntentService won't be killed by system? Since it is the same process which hosts UI thread, does it means that even app is in background, as long as the app has an intentService running it won't be killed by system?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> The intentService actually run in the same process, but a different thread called worker thread, right?

Objects in Java do not "run" in a thread. Methods are called on a thread. The `onHandleIntent()` method of an `IntentService` is called on a background thread.

> Does it means that the process which runs IntentService won't be killed by system?

No.

> Since it is the same process which hosts UI thread

**Every** process has a thread that is called its main application thread (or, sometimes, its UI thread). Threads are tied to processes; there is no single magic "UI thread" for the entire device.

> does it means that even app is in background, as long as the app has an intentService running it won't be killed by system?

No.

Comment: So if we do not specify any process which calls the onHandleIntent, the background thread which executes onHandlerIntent will be killed when system kill app?

Comment: @shuoweng: If by "system kill app" you mean "Android terminates the process that the service is in", then yes.